# No node_modules folder after npm install inside Docker

Tags: c#, docker, npm, .net-core, gcloud

For last few days I am trying to deploy asp.net core 3.1 application on Google Cloud App Engine service. I think, that I am pretty close but at the moment I have a problem with installation of npm packages.
Generally, I am serving node_modules folder as static files in my Razor pages application, so I have such a piece of code in my `Startup.cs` class:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "node_modules")),
  RequestPath = "/node_modules"
});
```

Google cloud does not support .net core 3.1 at the moment, so the only way to deploy the application is to deploy it as a Docker image.
So here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY myApp/myApp.csproj myApp/
COPY myApp.DataAccess/myApp.DataAccess.csproj myApp.DataAccess/
COPY myApp.Model/myApp.Model.csproj myApp.Model/
RUN dotnet restore myApp/myApp.csproj

# copy and build app and libraries
COPY myApp/ myApp/
COPY myApp.DataAccess/ myApp.DataAccess/
COPY myApp.Model/ myApp.Model/
WORKDIR /source/myApp
RUN dotnet build -c release

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c release --no-build -o /app

# npm libs
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY myApp/package.json .
COPY myApp/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm root

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

The docker build is successful, but when im trying to run the container there is such a exception:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/node_modules/
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
   at UniCableApp.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, RoleManager`1 roleManager, UserManager`1 userManager) in /source/UniCableApp/Startup.cs:line 113
```

I have created the image of stopped container using:

```
docker commit <id> <snapshot name>
```

After that I was able to inspect the image by:

```
docker run -ti --entrypoint=sh<snapshot name>
```

And there is no node_modules folder in the /app directory.
As I said, I am new in the world of Docker, so maybe someone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're copying `/app` from the `publish` image|layer and effectively ignoring the NPM install that you perform in the `FROM: node` layer.

`FROM: node` needs to `COPY --from=publish /app .` perhaps name that layer too.

And then the `runtime` layer needs to `COPY --from=2 /app .` too or whatever you decide to call the `node` layer.

You may need to use `/app/ ./` (terminating `/`) to ensure the copies are recursive.

I'm unsure whether you should include the `package-lock.json` file. I think you're correct in including it but it may be that this precludes the package installation. Don't know.

You can confirm that `/app/node_modules` is added and carried forward by adding the following to each layer and then checking the output when you build the images:

```
RUN ls -ld /app
```

> **NB** Google Cloud Platform's compute services are great for Microsoft's runtimes including .NET Core. I'm unclear what you mean by it not being supported.

#### Update: repro

I made a simpler repro of your example to show working:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY app/app.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore ./app.csproj

COPY app/ app/
RUN dotnet build

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app .
RUN ls -l /app

RUN dotnet publish

FROM node:10 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
RUN ls -l /app

COPY app/package.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm root

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=node /app .
RUN ls -l /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

And:

```
docker build --tag=60424677 --file=Dockerfile --no-cache .
```

yields (edited for clarity):

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.144kB
Step 1/23 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
...
Step 7/23 : FROM build AS publish
Step 9/23 : COPY --from=build /app .
Step 10/23 : RUN ls -l /app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Feb 27 20:41 app.csproj
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 obj
...
Step 12/23 : FROM node:10 as node
Step 14/23 : COPY --from=publish /app .
Step 15/23 : RUN ls -l /app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Feb 27 20:41 app.csproj
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:51 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 obj
...
Step 19/23 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
Step 21/23 : COPY --from=node /app .
Step 22/23 : RUN ls -l /app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 app
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Feb 27 20:41 app.csproj
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:51 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:51 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 27 20:50 obj
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  345 Feb 27 20:51 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  270 Feb 27 20:51 package.json
...
Successfully built 43ba6f8577e5
Successfully tagged 60424677:latest
```

Comment: Oh, now I understand. As soon as I will by back from work, I will check your hints.

Comment: In case of Google Cloud and .NET Core. 
I meant that, there is an easier way to deploy .net core application using Visual Studio and Google Cloud extension but at the moment the last supported version of .net core is 2.1.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the clarification